# what happens when you put enhancer and caat box in prokaryotes

Tags: genetics, biochemistry, dna, gene-regulation

what happens when you put enhancer and caat box in prokaryotes

Answer (score -1):

I do not think that enchancers do anything in procaryotes since there is no
chromatin spatial organization of DNA involved.